# Правильная передача смысла

Tags: смысл

Можно ли написать в строчке стихотворения:

"Меня невозможно сломить, как любовь"

В значении: Меня невозможно сломить, как невозможно сломить любовь. Или в данном случае меняется значение фразы и получается, что наоборот любовь можно сломить?

Comment: одни и те же предложения могут иметь разный смысл это нормально. Тут как минимум 3 смысла, "невозможно сломить как и любовь", "невозможно сломить как любовь, но можно сломить иначе", "невозможно сломить как любовь - ломаюсь на раз два"

Comment: Илья, зависит от того,  что будет дальше. И, может быть, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите так:

1. ***Меня, как любовь,** невозможно сломить.*

При таком расположении сначала следует сравнение **"меня, как любовь",**  а потом уже действие. Поэтому здесь **однозначный** смысл.

2. А иначе будет двусмысленность: *Меня невозможно сломить, **как невозможно/как можно** сломить любовь.*

Сравнительный оборот строится на основе сравнительного **придаточного,** а там могут быть варианты.